# How Gaussain beam exaclty be after diffraction between two mediums?

Tags: optics, laser, geometric-optics, fiber-optics, structural-beam

[image]

How it will be the refraction of the Gaussian beam, does one of its sides will go in distortion, and which equations can predict this distortion?
Sure I have to use Snell's law to know the angle but what about the distortion? or it will keep its shape?

Comment: Your question is about refraction not diffraction!  Also if we assume the 1st medium is air and the second medium is transparent ( like glass) there is effectively no distortion if the glass is flat.  If the glass is curved like a lens then detailed calculations are required to know the shape of the beam.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry I meant refraction! I changed it. So let's say n2 is air and n1 is glass, does the waist will stay the same? and do we get near field in the air and then the scattering field?!

Comment: Good glass (and there are many kinds in science in industry) will not scatterer if it's a smooth optical grade.  All glasses reflect about 4% from the front surface and another 3 % at the back, so 7% is not transmitted!  That is why AR (antireflection) coating is so important.

Comment: Thank you a lot for these information! Does we get anyway Near field (Evanescent field) at the surface?